# Use awk to find first occurrence

Tags: command-line, sed, awk, grep

I have a log file that gets updated when my script runs.  The script will insert "Start of script" text when it starts and "End of script" text when it finishes running.  I am trying to capture the text between the "Start of script" and "End of script".  The most recent entries are at the bottom of the log.

Using the following is close, but it is giving me all the occurrences in the log as shown below.

```
tac /opt/novell/JDBCFanout/activemqstatus.log |awk '/End of script/,/Start of script/'|tac

2014-09-09 12:30:42 - Start of script
2014-09-09 12:30:42 - Monitoring Reset script for the ActiveMQ.
2014-09-09 12:30:42 - The ActiveMQ value is not 1, the ActiveMQ services will not be restarted. The current value is 0.
2014-09-09 12:31:35 - The Fanout driver state is:  0
2014-09-09 12:33:32 - Sleeping for 10 seconds before checking the status of the Fanout driver.
2014-09-09 12:35:05 - The Fanout driver state is:  1
2014-09-09 12:35:05 - ERROR: The Fanout driver failed to start. The Fanout driver needs to be manually restarted.
2014-09-09 12:35:05 - End of script
2014-09-09 13:17:17 - Start of script
2014-09-09 13:17:17 - Reset script for the ActiveMQ.
2014-09-09 13:17:17 - The ActiveMQ flag is 1, shutting down the ActiveMQ services and the Fanout driver.
2014-09-09 13:17:17 - The ActiveMQ flag is now set to 0.
2014-09-09 13:17:17 - Stopping the Fanout driver.
2014-09-09 13:17:27 - The script is now cleaning up the pid's.
2014-09-09 13:17:37 - The script is now archiving the ActiveMQ Logs.
2014-09-09 13:17:37 - No files older than 60 days.
2014-09-09 13:17:47 - The script is now starting the ActiveMQ services.
2014-09-09 13:19:57 - The ActiveMQ service is running,
2014-09-09 13:19:57 - The ActiveMQ Oracle service is running.
2014-09-09 13:19:57 - The ActiveMQ MSSQL service is running.
2014-09-09 13:19:57 - The ActiveMQ Queue Manager service is running.
2014-09-09 13:19:58 - Sleeping for 10 seconds before checking the status of the Fanout driver.
2014-09-09 13:20:09 - The Fanout driver successfully restarted.
2014-09-09 13:20:09 - End of script
```

Specifically I would like for the output to look like this, and not the all occurences as shown above.

```
2014-09-09 13:17:17 - Start of script
2014-09-09 13:17:17 - Reset script for the ActiveMQ.
2014-09-09 13:17:17 - The ActiveMQ flag is 1, shutting down the ActiveMQ services and the Fanout driver.
2014-09-09 13:17:17 - The ActiveMQ flag is now set to 0.
2014-09-09 13:17:17 - Stopping the Fanout driver.
2014-09-09 13:17:27 - The script is now cleaning up the pid's.
2014-09-09 13:17:37 - The script is now archiving the ActiveMQ Logs.
2014-09-09 13:17:37 - No files older than 60 days.
2014-09-09 13:17:47 - The script is now starting the ActiveMQ services.
2014-09-09 13:19:57 - The ActiveMQ service is running,
2014-09-09 13:19:57 - The ActiveMQ Oracle service is running.
2014-09-09 13:19:57 - The ActiveMQ MSSQL service is running.
2014-09-09 13:19:57 - The ActiveMQ Queue Manager service is running.
2014-09-09 13:19:58 - Sleeping for 10 seconds before checking the status of the Fanout driver.
2014-09-09 13:20:09 - The Fanout driver successfully restarted.
2014-09-09 13:20:09 - End of script
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can share!

Comment: "The script is now cleaning up the pid's" -- the pid's what? I'm on the edge of my seat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps a little state machine:

```
tac file |
awk '/End of script/ {p=1} p {print} p && /Start of script/ {exit}' |
tac
```

Answer (score 1):

Arguably simpler than glenn’s answer
(although it does require typing “Start of script” twice):

```
tac logfile | awk '/End of script/,/Start of script/{print} /Start of script/{exit}' | tac
```

or

```
tac logfile | sed -n '/End of script/,/Start of script/p; /Start of script/q' | tac
```